# Problem with Android and windows.requestFileSystem

Tags: android, cordova

I use Cordova 3.6.3 and I have a phone with Android 8.0. The piece of code does not work, the app does not log any type of error, even circulating the "try-catch" function. Ideas? The phone is a BlackView.

```
var getFileSystemRoot = (function() {

  var root;

  var init = function() {
      window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 1024*1024,
          function(fileSystem) {
              root = fileSystem.root;
          }, 
          onFileSystemError);
  };
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", init, true); 

  return function() {
      return root;
  };
}()); // execute immediately
```

Comment: could you provide some more info? anything around? an error your getting? steps you've taken to debug it? any logs?

Comment: @Simone Acquaviva, i think, that new versions of android do not allow accessing the local storage without users permission. I think you should ask for permission in the first place

Answer (score 0):

The ***window.requestFileSystem()*** method is deprecated and should not be used.

[See the linked MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestFileSystem):
Though some browsers might still support it, it may have already been removed from the relevant web standards, may be in the process of being dropped, or may only be kept for compatibility purposes.